# match comments with added lines to get added comment lines in a file

Tags: python, git, comments, string-matching

I would like to extract all added comment lines for a specific file. In order to do this I extract all the comments with tokenize and ast.
Additionally, I would get all the added lines for this file from `git show commit -- pathfile` .

I am having troubles to get the added comment lines, especially if they are just empty lines. My matching code looks like this:

```
addedCommentLinesPerFile = []
    for commentline in parsedCommentLines:
               for line in addedLinesList:
                        if commentline == line or commentline in line:
                            try:
                                parsedCommentLines.remove(commentline)
                                addedLinesList.remove(line)
                            except ValueError:
                                continue
                            addedCommentLinesPerFile.append(commentline)
```

Let's say my file would like this:

```
def function():
+    print("hello") #prints hello
+
"""
foo

"""
```

So the lists would look like this:

```
parsedCommentLines = ["#prints hello","foo",""]
addedLinesList = ['    print("hello") #prints hello',""]
```

The desired output would be:

```
addedCommentLinesPerFile = ["#prints hello"]
```

But I would get:

```
addedCommentLinesPerFile = ["#prints hello",""]
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details, including sample data for ```parsedCommentLines```, ```addedLinesList```, etc. Also it's unclear what you mean by 'empty comment lines'.

Comment: @relent95 With empty comment lines I mean lines within a docstring which are empty. In my example, it would be the last line of docstring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`commentline in line` : will indeed always return `True` if commentline is empty, and will also work regardless of `line`.

If you want to *first* match the lines matching exactly *then* try to see if existing lines are subparts of the remaining lines, you could at least write two loops

the first one would only match `if commentline == line:`, the second one `if commentline in line:`

you may want to check extra conditions on `commentline` before checking `commentline in line` : minimum length, non white characters ...

---

If you want to check if a `# one line comment` sits *at the end of a string*, write that :

- check if `commentline` starts with a `#`
- check if it is a suffix : `if line.endswith(commentline)`

---

Another approach could be to generate two files which contain only the comment lines, and compare these two files to see how comments were modified.

On the git side of things :

- to list the files affected by `commit`, you can use :

  ```
  git show --format="" --name-only commit  # or --name-status
  ```
- for each of the modified files, you can get :

  - the content of the file *before* :

    ```
    git show commit~:path/to/file
    ```
  - the content of the file *after* :

    ```
    git show commit:path/to/file
    ```

From these two contents, you can use your code to extract comments, and either

- write them to two files (say `/tmp/comments.before` and  `/tmp/comments.after`) and just run `diff /tmp/comments.before /tmp/comments.after`
- keep the list of comment lines in your program, and use a lib that runs a `diff` like algorithm on two strings lists

Comment: Your suggestions would improve my code a lot. But one problem still remains: An empty added line would be matched with an empty comment line although it is not an added comment line, like I illustrated in the example.

Comment: I think the only way to work around my problem is to work with line numbers and then only match those with each other.

Comment: @Moe: the bottom line is : it's code, you can code whatever condition you see fit. If empty lines shouldn't be matched, remove them from your lists.

Comment: another suggestion : for each modified file, and each of its version (before,after) choose a way to write just the comment lines to a `comments.before`, `comments.after` file, then run `diff` on these two files.

Comment: I'm saying "file", it can also be : create your two list of lines in python (keeping only the comments), and use a lib that runs `diff` on two lists of strings

Comment: using `git` : you can get the list of modified files with `git show --format="" --name-only commit`, you can then get "the file before" using `git show commit~:path/to/file` and "the file after" using `git show commit:path/to/file`

Comment: Thats a very good suggestion. I had it on my mind as well but was hesitant due to my scripts performance but I think thats the most reliable way to go for.